# Detect the difference between the first click redirection and the end redirect page

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Android has methods like `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, which detects the redirect, and `onLoadResource()`, which detects when the resource loads.

I need to detect the final landing/end URL for a given request; is there a Cocoa Touch counterpart to this? I have a `UIWebView` and it randomly opens either a "click-to-play" YouTube video loaded by an HTML script, or a regular webpage which has a click-through URL.

```
[_contentView loadHTMLString:_interstitialScript baseURL:nil];
```

My dilemma is this: how can I detect if the page loaded is a YouTube video, or regular webpage? My initial thought was to use something like that `onLoadResourse()` method, but I don't know what the equivalent is.

Comment: additionally: I was thinking of using [request mainDocumentURL] but I am loading the content with [webview loadHTMLstring...]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method will tell you when its done and then you can look at the `request` object on the UIWebView to figure out where it is at.

Comment: hmm i see but can i make a request, catch the landing page with this "webViewDidFinishLoad:" method, then do something accordingly without making the UIWebView navigate outside

Comment: @GurinderSingh use the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` delegate method for that

Comment: ohh Thanks! im going to use this